# update html and css before scripts run

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm new in JS, i have a 3x3 table filled as below:

```
  <table id="mytable">
    <tr>
      <td id="1" onclick="select_home(1)"></td>
      <td id="2" onclick="select_home(this.id)"></td>
      <td id="3" onclick="select_home(this.id)"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="4" onclick="select_home(this.id)"></td>
      <td id="5" onclick="select_home(this.id)"></td>
      <td id="6" onclick="select_home(this.id)"></td>
    </tr>+
    <tr>
      <td id="7" onclick="select_home(this.id)"></td>
      <td id="8" onclick="select_home(this.id)"></td>
      <td id="9" onclick="select_home(this.id)"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

im updating template whenever a click happen on tables as below:

```
var table = document.querySelector("table");
// listen for a click
table.addEventListener("click", function (ev) {
  // get the event targets ID
  var serviceID = ev.target.id;
  turn() ? blue_checked(serviceID) : red_checked(serviceID);
});

function blue_checked(id) {
  var table = document.getElementById("mytable").getElementsByTagName("td");
  selected_home_blue.push(id);
  table[id - 1].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  check_game(selected_home_blue, "blue");
}
```

i am updating background color of td's first then run check_game function but check_game run first and then td background color change, how can i handle it ?

Comment: Why would `check_game` run first?

Comment: there is an alert() in check game function, i got the alert first and then it changes @KonradLinkowski

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? adding an onclick attribute to a td is already a bad use. Besides of that, it would most likely easier to simply use a single  eventListener and an event delegation.

Comment: One error I notice is that you pass the `id` as a string, but then you try to subtract one from the id with `table[id-1]`. If you want to treat the `id` as a number you could use `parseInt(id)`. By the way, your code snippet misses a lot of code so it's kind of hard for us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: String + number subtraction works fine in js

Comment: `alert` isn't a good way to check if something runs first.  `alert` can show up before the dom update. Using `alert` is a bad practice usually anyway.

Comment: Here's how I'd approach this: https://jsfiddle.net/gb4L6hjy/

Comment: That also still has the same problem with the alert box :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified your cell-coloring code. You can directly get the table cell that needs to be colored using the id. You can show a message with your own div instead of using an `alert()`. This prevents the problem that the `alert()` always shows before the DOM is actually changed.

```
const table = document.querySelector("table");
const messagebox = document.querySelector("message");

// listen for a click
table.addEventListener("click", function (ev) {
  // get the event targets ID
  const serviceID = ev.target.id;
  blue_checked(serviceID); // example for blue
});

function blue_checked(id) {
  const tablecell = document.getElementById(id);
  tablecell.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  showMessage("blue played")
}

function showMessage(msg) {
  messagebox.innerText = msg
}
```

And in your HTML add the message box

```
<div id="message"></div>
```

Comment: it's depends on turn() function, once blue and once red. actually im trying to make a tictoctoe game

Comment: I understand, I just color the blue cells here as an example of how you could achieve it, since you didn't include the code for the `turn()` function.

Comment: still didnt work for me. the alert function in check_game happen first!

Comment: The alert box gets triggered before the DOM changes, like @Konrad Linkowski mentioned. There is no way around this. The more common solution is to create your own modal box or text box with CSS and javascript, and display your user messages in there instead of using `alert()`.

Comment: i learned smt new here! dank je wel ;)

Comment: geen probleem !